# Programmatically changing the width of DockWindow

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, width

I have the following code:

```
var hWindow1 = new HostWindow(new Control() {Dock= DockStyle.Fill}, DockType.ToolWindow);
radDock1.DockWindow(hWindow1, DockPosition.Left);

var hWindow2 = new HostWindow(new Control() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, DockType.ToolWindow);
radDock1.DockWindow(hWindow2, DockPosition.Bottom); 

var hWindow3 = new HostWindow(new Control() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, DockType.ToolWindow);
radDock1.DockWindow(hWindow3, DockPosition.Right);            

var hWindow4 = new HostWindow(new Control() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, DockType.Document);            
radDock1.DockWindow(hWindow4, DockPosition.Fill);

var hWindow5 = new HostWindow(new Control() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, DockType.Document);
radDock1.AddDocument(hWindow5, hWindow1, DockPosition.Fill);
```

How can I change programmatically a width of some DockWindow (for example `hWindow3`)?

Comment: I have done it! :) I have found very useful link:
http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-object-model-example-building-an-advanced-layout-at-runtime.html

You can change RadDock size, if you use RadDock.TabStrip.SizeInfo property. You should specify RadDock.TabStrip.SizeInfo.SizeMode and 
RadDock.TabStrip.SizeInfo.AbsoluteSize (or RadDock.TabStrip.SizeInfo.RelativeRatio) properties. It is writen by the link in details.

Comment: If this was the answer, please formally answer the question and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your container is "Container". you can set the SizeMode to Absolute and set your desired size. 
This [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-object-model-example-building-an-advanced-layout-at-runtime.html) is very good.

Container.SizeInfo.SizeMode = SplitPanelSizeMode.Absolute;

Container.SizeInfo.AbsoluteSize = new Size(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);